# Rails - Allow access to controller action only to server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have `users` and `projects` scaffolds in my Rails project.  I also have an `admin` controller and view that is only accessible to admin users.  I want the `index` and `create` controller actions for the `users` and `projects` models to be only accessible to the `admin` view (using `render :partial > 'index'`) but I do not want to let the visitors to the site to be able to type in `http://railsapp.host/users` and get the partial rendered.  How do I achieve this?

TO clarify, my issue is not about the user role.  I have authlogic with all the require_admin helpers but I dont even want an admin user to be able to access the `index` route for `users` directly from the browser.  In effect I want to limit the `index` controller action only to the view code of `admin#index` like this:

```
<%= render '/users/index' %>
```

Comment: The simplest way is described here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-authentications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should have said I was a relative noob to rails.  I figured it out though.  I thought the

```
<%= render '/users/index' %>
```

actually goes through the `users#index` code.  I just figured out that it was just calling the partial under the views without going through the controller action.  So I simply added this to the `users` controller

```
def index
  redirect_to :controller=>'admin', :action=>'index'
end
```

And that seems to achieve the goal I was seeking.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

The best rails way is define a filter in  application controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :check_isadmin?, :only => [:create, :index]
 end
 class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :check_isadmin?, :only => [:create, :index]
 end
 class ApplicationControlloller < ApplicationController
   def check_isadmin?
      current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wasn't clear in my question - I just edited it.  Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use role for different user, you can check the role of admin user then render partial, ex:

```
<% if user.isAdmin? %>
  <%= render 'index' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wasn't clear in my question - I just edited it.  Please see edit.

Comment: i'm not understand what you want to do yet, but if you want to set abilities of users, you can try [Can Can](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem.

Comment: Thanh, I have a `users#index` controller action that renders a partial.  But this partial is embedded in the `admin#index` view.  I dont want anyone to be able to type in `https://localhost/users` and get the partial.  In effect I need to be able to discern in my users controller whether the request is coming from a web address typed in directly into the browser, or coming during the rendering of `admin#index` action.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing on Aayush Khandelwal answer which was helpful for me **before_filter is depreciated on Rails 5**. Use before_action instead.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :check_isadmin?, :only => [:create, :index]
end
```

and in :check_isadmin? redirecto to an other page if false.

```
def check_isadmin?
  if current_user == nil || !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```